# Lookup return only if find correspondence

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I need to check if two collections have correspondent data. I have the collections like:

```js
colA = [
  { _id: UUID('8af051fd-feaa-4a81-b34f-327513210eab'), docId: '12345689', name: 'Office 1', country: 'Spain' },
  { _id: UUID('87c36ae2-5e9f-4cda-9bf5-087e96fb71b9'), docId: '12345680', name: 'Office 2', country: 'San Tomé e Príncipe' },
  { _id: UUID('7ec73cb0-657a-4a91-861c-fccf04c8c2a7'), docId: '12345688', name: 'Office 3', country: 'Canada' }
];

colB = [
  { id: 1, docId: '12345689', name: 'Office 1', smtp: null },
  { id: 2, docId: '12345680', name: 'Office 2', smtp: 'smtp.gmail.com' },
  { id: 3, docId: '12345688', name: 'Office 3', smtp: 'smtp.office365' },
  { id: 4, docId: '12345638', name: 'Office 4', smtp: 'smtp.host.com' },
  { id: 5, docId: '12345699', name: 'Office 5', smtp: '123.321.456' },
];
```

I need to return a new list, containing only the documents that have a correspondence in both collections. I will use a field like `docId` in the lookup.

Expected result:

```js
result = [
  { _id: UUID('8af051fd-feaa-4a81-b34f-327513210eab'), docId: '12345689', name: 'Office 1', country: 'Spain', smtp: null },
  { _id: UUID('87c36ae2-5e9f-4cda-9bf5-087e96fb71b9'), docId: '12345680', name: 'Office 2', country: 'San Tomé e Príncipe', smtp: 'smtp.gmail.com' },
  { _id: UUID('7ec73cb0-657a-4a91-861c-fccf04c8c2a7'), docId: '12345688', name: 'Office 3', country: 'Canada', smtp: 'smtp.host.com' }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$lookup` - *colA* LEFT JOIN *colB* and return the correspond document(s) from *colB* as `bList` array.
2. `$match` - Filter the document with `bList` is not an empty array.
3. `$set` - Set the `smtp` field by getting the first value from the `bList.smtp` array.
4. `$unset` - Remove the `bList` field from the document.

```
db.colA.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "colB",
      "localField": "docId",
      "foreignField": "docId",
      "as": "bList"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      bList: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      smtp: {
        $first: "$bList.smtp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "bList"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_z3YN97cMN-)